# Show N number of Labels on a window with a given Number

Tags: python, tkinter

I have `N` elements which I would like to show on a window, let's say `N=9`

The expected output is:

[image]

but, if I change N to 10 I get the same result!
This is because I do this by calculating the square root of N and basically creating a 2d array of it, but you can't calculate a square root of 10 because you'll get a float number back, so you need to add additional lines for these leftovers.

I can't manage to do it myself, so I would be super happy if someone can supply a quick solution, thanks!

My full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')

N = 9
div1 = int(math.sqrt(N))
for i in range(div1):
    for j in range(div1):
        root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
        root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
        frame = Frame(
            master=root,
            relief=RAISED,
            borderwidth=0
        )
        frame.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=2, pady=2)

        label = Label(master=frame, text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}",font=0.5, fg='#fff', bg='#000000', width=10)
        labels.append(label)
        #label.config(fg='#078520')
        label.pack(padx=0, pady=0)
        usernames.remove(usernames[0])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So basically you want to find 2 integers when multiplied give `N` (in this case 10). You also want to the integers to be as close as possible to the `sqrt(N)` (so that the labels look closer to a grid). Is that right? What do you want to happen when `N` is 10? 2 rows of 5 columns?

Comment: Check for factors of the number?

Comment: Yes, if N is 10 2 rows of 5 columns works @TheLizzard

Comment: some of the numbers don't have a "normal" factors, for example if N=503, your only option would be to have 1 row and 503 columns. @CoolCloud

Comment: So what do you want to happen in case of 503?

Comment: 22 rows of 22 and 1 row of 19?

Comment: I think the right way to go about this would be, to fix a dimension in your mind. For example, 5 columns. Then you can always check the number of rows required and even maybe add an extra row for the sake of it. Also, why are you indefinitely making grid? What is this for, could be an XY problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import math

def create_labels(root, N):
    div1 = int(math.sqrt(N))
    div2 = N // div1

    labels = []
    for i in range(div1+1):
        for j in range(div2):
            root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
            root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
            label = Label(root, text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}", fg="white", bg="black", width=10)
            label.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=2, pady=2)
            labels.append(label)
            if len(labels) == N:
                return labels
    # The code should never reach this point if my brain is actually working but still:
    return labels

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")

N = 48

labels = create_labels(root, N)

root.mainloop()
```

It calculates the rows and columns needed to the closest square number (downwards) so for 13, the square number is 9. Then it loops through the required number of columns + 1 to make sure it accounts for the left overs. It then uses an if statement to check if the number of labels shown is equal to `N`.

Comment: That worked for this example.
But try it when N=13, you get 1 row of 13 columns. What I want to happen in this case is for example 4 rows of 4 columns, for the 4th row, I want it to have only 1 columns because that's what left.

Comment: @yarinCohen Sorry I misunderstood. I am working on a solution right now.

Comment: @CoolCloud Good point I misunderstood OP's requirements. I am working on a better solution right now

Comment: @yarinCohen Can you please try it out now? I think it fit's your requirements. I am typing an explanation right now :D

Comment: `break` should do it, perfect. Though I am curious, why indefinite rows and cols @yarinCohen

Comment: Basically I will be using N=500+ so if I'll show it all on one row I wouldn't see all elements. @CoolCloud

Comment: @yarinCohen Just a note: having 500+ widgets can make your GUI very slow. It did on my computer when I had 250 entries.

Comment: Can't believe I manage to find so many bugs. try when N=48, you'll get  7 rows of 8 columns which is 56. @TheLizzard

Comment: @yarinCohen Sorry, I edited my answer. I checked it with N=12, ..., 16, 45. So it should work now. Sorry for the troubles. It's late here and my brain has decided to go to sleep early today.

Comment: that's ok haha, I really appriciate the help, thank you! @TheLizzard